# Visual Studio DB-connection not showing up in Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I've opened a database connection through the Tools-menu. It's working without problem and showing me my database and it's tables.

However, following [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/create-dbcontext-in-entity-framework5.aspx) tutorial, I should be able to select my connection in the connection-dropdown the wizard shows me. The dropdown is empty, so I tried creating a new connection. However, when selecting the Data Source upon creating a new connection, there is no "MySQL Database"-source, preventing me from re-creating the connection. I've scourged Google, I've scourged SE, but I can't find anyone with the same problem who's offered a solution that worked for me.

As far as I can tell, VS isn't the problem, as it's connected effortlessly. The problem is the Entity Wizard not acknowledging MySQL Databases as datasource, and I can't figure out how I resolve this. I've installed both "My.Sql.Data" and "MySql.Data.Entity" packages with the NuGet packages manager, alongside the "EntityFramework". I should be having everything that I need?

I'm using VS 2015 Community, .NET 4.5 and Entity 6.2
I'm using HeidiSQL as database-manager and XAMPP to host the MySQL-server (hope I'm stating this correctly?)

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

ConnectionString, below the startup brackets and above the entityFramework brackets.
`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="finance" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=finance;uid=root;password=" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Provider settings
`<providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider></providers>`

Comment: Show your connection string and provider config settings. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Comment: @SteveGreene I've edited the mainpost